# JUnit in a call to an interface into a method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I want to cover some lines of code using JUnit methods and Mockito. I have a method with the following structure:

```
public void myMethod() {
    Class1 element = object.method(new InterfaceClass() {
        @Override
        public void interfaceMethod() {
            // Some code
        }
    }
});
```

I need to cover the code of the overrided method, but when I test the method myMethod, I only cover the call to the object.method().

In my JUnit class I've implemented a method with a instruction like:

```
this.myclass.myMethod();
```

How can I reach the code of the interface's method?

I can't give us more datails about the code, I hope you can know what my problem is.

Comment: What does `object.method()` do? Does it actually call the `interfaceMethod()`? If possible post the code of that method...

Comment: It establishes a conection to a webservice and analyses the response.

I can't give you more details because it's a private code of my company...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what do you mean with "reach the code of interface's method". Do you mean the code you have in `interfaceMethod()` is not executed when you call `this.myclass.myMethod()` in your JUnit test?

Comment: Exactly, that's my problem

Comment: If `object.method` doesn't call `interfaceMethod`, then that's the problem. It hasn't got anything to do with Mockito or testing. If `object.method` calls `interfaceMethod`, then your test will cover it.

Comment: So, if the code of the `object.method` doesn't call the interface's method it's imposible to cover it, isn't it? Thank you very much

Comment: If the code of `object.method` doesn't do anything with the `InterfaceClass` object then yes, it will be hard to test it, because it only exists as a parameter to the method... You could refactor that to change it, for example by introducing an `InterfaceClassFactory`.

Comment: Ok Florian, I'll do that. Thank you

Comment: ( Of course, if the method doesn't do anything with it, I really don't get why you create the InterfaceClass object in the first place... Probably something that's been lost in the minimizing of this example.)